# Selenium dump js state. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, python, debugging, selenium

I am using selenium to interact with website that does horribly complicated javascript things. It's not my website so I don't have control over it.

Occasionally (but very seldom) the website sortof hangs. It seems to be stuck in some kind of js loop, or it's waiting for something that just isn't happening. I can detect when this happens, I would like to know why it happens.

So my idea is to do some kind of js state dump - I want to know what js code is executing right now, what called it, variable values, all that good stuff.

The error only occurs once every 50 or so runs. Each of which takes quite some time. So ideally I would be able to get this to work without manual intervention, and I would want to use the same function elsewhere.

eg pseudocode:

```
perform_some_browser_actions()
if sanity_checks_fail():
    dump_js()
```

Is there a way to do this? I've done a lot of googling and coming up blank, maybe I'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: Use Inspector window and debug and find out

Comment: @Madhan:can you give me a link or anything that explains your point? Ideally I would like to have the thing dump without manual intervention